# Perform data transformation on training data inside cross validation

Tags: transformation, cross-validation, h2o

I would like to do cross validation for 5 folds. In each fold, I have a training and valid set. However, due to data issue, I need to transform my data. First, I transform the training data, train the model,apply the transformation rule to the validation data, and then test the model. I need to redo the transformation for every fold. How would I do that in H2O? I can't find away to separate the transformation part out. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: why not do all the transformation you need first, and then specify `nfolds=5` when you build your model?

Comment: Because I do not want to leak to my validation data. The transformation is not regular transformation such as normalization.

Comment: which products you know that support data transformations with CV without data leakage? h2o doesn't so far but Driverless AI by h2o.ai does support its transformations without data leakage, e.g. cv target-encoding. It's a separate product though.

Comment: I do not plan to use driverless AI for now. How about Scikit-learn? I do not find it there though in case I am mistaken.

Comment: Scikit have a Pipeline class which is used for this