# H2O Gain/Lift table

Tags: response, h2o

My question is about H2O Gain/Lift table. I understand that the response rate is the proportion of all the events that fall into the group/bin. HOW to get that pieces of data that fall into bin 1, bin 2, etc.? **I want to see how the key variables look in each group/bin in respect to the Response Rate.**

It would be great to have a full description of how the measures in Gain/Lift table are calculated (formulas)

Comment: nothing here should be specific to h2o. for details on how Gain/Lift charts work, for example see here: http://www.saedsayad.com/model_evaluation_c.htm

Comment: please see previous questions on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521844/what-are-the-column-definitions-for-h2os-gains-lift-table,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404805/h2o-model-performance-metric-and-gains-chart-customization/  and here is a link to the documentation section, that tells you how you can see results in Flow: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html#interpreting-the-gains-lift-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations for the Gains and Lift Chart can be found in this file: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/GainsLift.java

Which shows:

E  = total number of events

N  = number of observations

G  = number of groups (10 for deciles or 20 for demi-deciles)

P  = overall proportion of observations that are events (P = E/N)

ei = number of events in group i, i=1,2,...,G

ni = number of observations in group i

pi = proportion of observations in group i that are events (pi = ei/ni)

groups: are hard coded to 16; if there are fewer than 16 unique probability values, then the number of groups is reduced to the number of unique quantile thresholds.

cumulative data fraction =  sum_n_i/N

lower_threshold = set by quantile bins

lift = pi/P

cumulative_lift = (Σiei/Σini)/P

response_rate = 100*pi

cumulative_response_rate = 100*Σiei/Σini

capture_rate = 100*ei/E

cumulative_capture_rate = 100*Σiei/E

gain = 100*(lift-1)

cumulative_gain = 100*(sum_lift-1)

average_response_rate = E/N

So here is a example walkthrough using the H2O-3 Python API:

```
import h2o
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
h2o.init()

# import and split the dataset
cars = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/junit/cars_20mpg.csv")

convert response column to a factor
cars["economy_20mpg"] = cars["economy_20mpg"].asfactor()

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors = ["displacement","power","weight","acceleration","year"]
response = "economy_20mpg"

# split dataset
train, valid = cars.split_frame(ratios=[.7],seed=1234)

# Initialize and train a GBM
cars_gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(seed = 1234)
cars_gbm.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, validation_frame=valid) 

# Generate Gains and Lift Table
# documentation on this parameter can be found here:
# http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?#h2o.model.H2OBinomialModel.gains_lift
gainslift = cars_gbm.gains_lift(train=False, valid=True, xval=False)
```

#### Table Overview

As expected we have 16 groups, because this is the hardcoded default behavior.

- Cumulative data fractions
- Threshold probability value
- Response rates (proportion of observations that are events in a group)
- Cumulative response rate
- Event capture rate
- Cumulative capture rate
- Gain (difference in percentages between the overall proportion of events and the observed proportion of observations that are events in the group)
- Cumulative gain

#### What if I Want Just the Deciles

By default the Gains and Lift Table provides you with more then just the deciles or ventiles, what this means is you have more flexibilty to pick out the percentiles in which you are interested.

Let's take the example of getting our deciles. In this example we see that we can start at row 6, skip row 7 and then take the rest of the rows to get our deciles.

Since the Gains and Lift Table returns a TwoDimTable we can use our group numbers as selection indices.

```
# show gains and lift table data type
print('H2O Gains Lift Table is of type: ', type(gainslift))
H2O Gains Lift Table is of type:  <class 'h2o.two_dim_table.H2OTwoDimTable'>

# since this table is small and for ease of use let's covert to a pandas dataframe
pandas_gl = gainslift.as_data_frame()
pandas_gl.set_index('group')


gainslift_deciles = pandas_gl.iloc[pd.np.r_[5,7:16], :]
gainslift_deciles
```

What if I Want Just the Ventiles

Those are available to select out as well, so let's do that next.

```
gainslift_ventiles = pandas_gl.iloc[pd.np.r_[7,9,11,13,15], :]
gainslift_ventiles
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lauren!

Comment: Hi Lauren, just following up the above question: am I right when I think that you mean the events are the outcomes 1 or 0?

Comment: @LanaKH, in this case you can think of the event as the outcome being one. For example if you are trying to see how well your model can predict people who are going to buy versus not buy, the event would be when someone buys. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Lauren Hi, may I ask a question about h2o here? Is transformation/preprocessing inside cross validation currently available? Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915750/perform-data-transformation-on-training-data-inside-cross-validation). Thanks!